# Adding spacing to each \par also affects spacing in the Index

Tags: table-of-contents, paragraphs, vertical-spacing

I am trying to increase the spacing between each paragraph and that is what I did to do so:

```
     '\documentclass{article}

      \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
      \usepackage[english]{babel}

      \setlength{\parindent}{1em} % Indent of 1em
      \setlength{\parskip}{1em}. % Spacing between paragraphs of 1em

      \begin{document}

      \tableofcontents

      \listoffigures

      \listoftables

       \chapter

          This is the text in first paragraph. This is the text in first 
          paragraph. This is the text in first paragraph. 
          \par
          This is the text in second paragraph...

       \end{document}'
```

And it correctly adds the spacings I want.

However, it also adds spacing between each line of the the table of contents, list of figures and list of tables. Without the command "\setlength{\parskip}{1em}" I had no spacing between paragraphs and in the table of contents, such as shown here:
[image: No spacing between lines in the index], [image: No spacing between paragraphs]
but with this command I have a spacing of 1em both between each line of the table of contents and between paragraphs, as you can see here:
[image: Spacing between each line in the Index], [image: Spacing between paragraphs.]
How to prevent latex from doing this, and leave the spacing between paragraphs only, and not inside the table of contents, list of figures and list of tables?

Thank you.

Comment: Just move the `\setlength` macros after `\tableofcontents`...

Comment: Thank you campa. It worked. So easy

Comment: BTW, `article` class has no `\chapter` (your snippet fails to compile)... ;-)